# Windows Batch file enable quick edit for gitbash

Tags: windows, batch-file, git-bash

I managed to launch gitbash from a bat file, I want also to enable quick edit mode how to do that ? thanks.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"
mode con: cols=160 lines=78
start sh.exe --login -i
```

Comment: If you enable quick-edit once, any future shell windows will support it.

Comment: it does not when you do it  through a batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a registry key to enable QuickEdit mode on all console windows launched by the current user.

```
reg add "HKCU\Console" /v "QuickEdit" /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

You should only need to run this command once, until you switch users or reinstall your OS.